# Load GeoJSON files as a JavaScript variable. Using Require.js

Tags: leaflet, javascript, mapbox, jquery

Trying to load a taluka.geojson

With reference to this post here [this guys post with require][1]

I am sure my GeoJSON file works [Here is a sample][2]

Here is my code:

```
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="./example-jquery-cdn-master/www/js/lib/require.js"></script>
    <style>
        #mapid {
            height: 800px;
        }
    </style>
</head>


<body>
    <div aria-role="Country Map" id="map"></div>
</body>

<script>
    //Loading the data State Shapes
    var json = require('./taluka.geojson'); //with path
    // because the path is in json,passed json as a variable
    var statesData = (json, cb) => {
        fs.readFile(require.resolve(json), (err, data) => {
            if (err)
                cb(err)
            else
                cb(null, JSON.parse(data))
        })
    }

    // Displaying Maps
    var mapboxAccessToken =
        'pk.eyJ1Ijoid2ljazNkIiwiYSI6ImNrN3NhZGUyYzBoYjMzZnFycDh2ZWhodGUifQ.pqYC2t8W0pKQ9neMEoGmjw';
    var map = L.map('map').setView([37.8, -96], 4);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=' + mapboxAccessToken, {
        id: 'mapbox/light-v9',
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1
    }).addTo(map);

    L.geoJson(statesData).addTo(map);

</script>
```

Here is the error:

```
require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Module name "taluka.geojson" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use     
require([])    
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded    
    at makeError (require.js:168)    
    at Object.localRequire [as require]
```

Here is my file structure just in case:

[image]

Comment: Links to references are missing.

Comment: It sounds like this problem and a solution are described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446844/dynamic-require-in-requirejs-getting-module-name-has-not-been-loaded-yet-for-c